# Filtering a nested list and out put as tree

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class as below

```
public class Material
{
  public string `MaterialName` { get; set; }
  public List<Material> `ChildMaterial` { get; set; }

}
```

I have created a nested list using the above class as in example below

- Material A
- Material B
- Material C

  - **Material D**
- Material J

  - **Material D**

    - Material F
- Material 2

I want a linq query on some method which will filter out **Material D** and will give me the path till the root and will remove all the nodes below it. As per below example this **Material D** can be found at any levels in the tree and may be repeated.

- Material A
- Material B
- Material C
- Material D
- Material J
- Material D

Answer (score 0):

At first you need a LINQ method that is able to flatten such a tree structure, so that you are able to iterate over all available nodes:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Map<TSource>(
  this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
  Func<TSource, bool> selectorFunction,
  Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TSource>> getChildrenFunction)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    if (selectorFunction == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("selectorFunction");

    if (getChildrenFunction == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("getChildrenFunction");

    return MapImpl(source, selectorFunction, getChildrenFunction);
}

private static IEnumerable<TSource> MapImpl<TSource>(
  IEnumerable<TSource> source,
  Func<TSource, bool> selectorFunction,
  Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TSource>> getChildrenFunction)
{
    // Go through the input enumerable looking for children,
    // and add those if we have them
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        foreach (var childElement in MapImpl(getChildrenFunction(element), selectorFunction, getChildrenFunction))
        {
            yield return childElement;
        }

        if (selectorFunction(element))
            yield return element;
    }
}
```

With this you can now run through your master list and find all desired nodes:

```
var matchingMaterials = MyMaterials.Map(material => true, material => material, material => material.ChildMeterials)
                                   .Where(material => material.Name = "Material D")
                                   // Materialization is needed, cause manipulation is desired while iterating over the result.
                                   .ToList();
```

Then you like to manipulate these nodes somehow (e.g. remove all child nodes from the matching nodes):

```
foreach(var material in matchingMaterials)
{
    material.ChildMaterials.Clear();
}
```